# How can I check if S3 objects is encrypted using boto?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm writing a python scripts to find out whether S3 object is encrypted. I tried using following code but key.encrypted always returns None even though I can see the object on S3 is encrypted.

```
keys = bucket.list()
for k in keys:
    print k.name, k.size, k.last_modified, k.encrypted , "\n"
```

k.encrypted always returns None.

Comment: I confirm these results. Strange! I wonder if `boto3` has this fixed?

Comment: Raised issue against `boto`: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3361

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, you can do this using `boto3` (which can be used side-by-side with `boto`).

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = s3.Object(bucket.name, obj.key)
    print key.server_side_encryption
```

See the `boto3` [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object) for a list of available key attributes.

Answer (score 2):

expanding on @mfisherca's response, you can do this with the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> --key <key>

# or query the value directly

aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> --key <key> \
  --query ServerSideEncryption --output text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the encryption state for specific objects using the `head_object` call.  Here's an example in Python/boto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
head = s3_client.head_object(
    Bucket="<S3 bucket name>",
    Key="<S3 object key>"
)
if 'ServerSideEncryption' in head:
    print head['ServerSideEncryption']
```

See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object

Comment: How can I get the status for all the objects not a specific objects , I want to know encryption status of all the objects in a specific bucket.

Comment: @manda1238 David Morales's answer loops through all objects and returns the encryption status of each.  You can't get the status of all objects in a single API call, if that is what you were hoping.